# How do I use a Homography Matrix properly?

Tags: opencv, mapping, pixel, panoramas, homography

So I have an image, and a panoramic image. Pixels from `image1` are mapped to the panorama using a Homography matrix (is that correct?). I have the Homography Matrix `H`.

So, for each pixel in panorama, how do I know where the pixel is in `image1`?

I have the (u,v) coordinates of the pixel in the panorama, an the Homography `H` that maps image1 to panorama.

What is the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *reverse* formula would be: p'=[wx,wy,w] = [u,v,1]*H^-1;
where H^-1 is the inverse of H; (it exists by definition)
dividing by the homogeneous coordinate w:
p = p'/w = [x,y,1],  where the coordinates [x,y] map to [u,v] in the panorama.

The intermediate result p' is a 3-dimensional vector, where the two first elements have to divided by the last one. This applies to both forward and reverse operations.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography